# How can I find and edit the php.ini file?

Tags: php

I am trying to find the `php.ini` file on Ubuntu server with the command:

```
sudo vim /etc/php5
```

However, this tells me that the file does not exist. How can I find and edit the `php.ini` file?

Comment: use `locate php.ini` I found mine that way.

Comment: try sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini then when you're done making changes,
type **ctrl+x** to close, and then **y** to save.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/356990/582516

Answer (score 4):

With ubuntu find command

```
sudo find / -name "php.ini"
```

or you can see the phpinfo page

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using apache2, it's located in `/etc/php5/apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers can correctly locate  `php.ini` files in the system, but to find out which one is used by the process you are running, you can use the [php_ini_loaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) function.

Note that the file loaded is different depending on how you invoke php (apache, nginx, command line, etc).

This information is also available through `phpinfo()`