# Php.ini file change not reflecting in phpinfo()

Tags: apache2, php, configuration

My php.ini settings are not reflected in phpinfo. It still shows `upload_max_filesize` as 2M but I have set it to 50M in php.ini. Can you please tell how to change php.ini properly? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I made changes to file in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` as described in [Find the correct php.ini file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file/356990#356990) and also restarted apache server and even restarted my laptop. Is this the right php.ini file I'm making changes to? What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Some time it happens that in `php.ini`, there is some syntax error on some line number for example

```
error_reporting = E_ALL && ~E_DEPRECATED && ~E_STRICT
```

In this case the apache does not load configuration after that line number. So this is bit complex to figure out syntax error in `php.ini` therefore you should try other ways to fix and you should try this solution at the end.

Comment: It took me two days to find this issue thanks for sharing such a wonderful insight!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) too.

According to php manual:

```
 post_max_size integer
    Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. 
    To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. 
    If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects
    file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than
    post_max_size.
```