# Compile php-ssh2 module from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php

Because I install PHP5.6.31 from source so I can't use this command:

```
apt-get install php-ssh2
```

to install SSH2 module for PHP.

Now I try to install this module from source. I read this install [step](http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php)

> ```
> 1. download the libssh2 package from http://libssh2.org, command as following:
>    tar vxzf libssh2-1.4.2.tar.gz
>    cd libssh2-1.4.2
>    ./configure
>    make
>    make install
> ```
>
> 2. download the php-ssh2 package from http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2:
>
> ```
> tar vxzf ssh2-0.11.3
> cd ssh2-0.11.3
> phpize
> ./configure --with-ssh2
> make
> make install
>
> and the ssh2.so file will copy into /usr/lib64/php/modules
> check it.
> ```
>
> 3. modify the php.ini
>
> vi /etc/php.ini add the "extension=ssh2.so" to the extension part of
>   php.ini
>
> 4. check the environment of php, use phpinfo();

But I fail in step 2:
[image]

Please help me. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: Please avoid upload terminal screenshot, instead copy the output to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the package which essential in order to run the script properly, simply install.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Comment: yes, it's work, thank you, but can you help me this step copy to "/usr/lib64/php/modules" and step 3 "modify the php.ini", because I install from source so I can found these file.

Comment: I think the "and the ssh2.so file will copy into `/usr/lib64/php/modules`" part is automatic as you ran `make` and `make install`. The manual tell you to check whether the actual file is already copied to `/usr/lib64/php/modules`.

Comment: And the `php.ini` file is a configuration setting for php, you need to modify them in order to load the extension. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file.