# Php code shows in source code

Tags: php

for some reason my php short code isn't working after I changed my ini file. I still see the code in the source code of the browser

```
<? include 'file/path'; ?>
```

but I changed a few of them to the `<?PHP` to see what would happen and those work just fine.

Comment: Is the file itself a .php file?  (Without being able to see the code in the page itself, I can't even begin to fathom the core problem here)

Comment: no it is a php file

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a note: PHP themselves actually suggests **not** using short-tags like this.  [PHP's own syntax manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) even mentions this, because short-tags support is not a default option - it either has to be compiled into PHP or enabled in the `php.ini` file:

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Because short-tags are not a default-supported thing, this is why `<? ... ?>` is rendered as-is and not processed as PHP.

If you *really* want to make this work, then you have to set in your `php.ini` files for the PHP configurations this:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Depending on what web server or PHP proxy handling system you use, you may have differing `php.ini` locations.  (This is, however, discussed in other questions and answers, such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/356990).)

**However**, as PHP themselves don't recommend using short tags, you should really consider *not* using short-tags at all in your PHP code.