# there is no php.ini file in my ubuntu system

Tags: apache2, php

Below is the code from my system, I could not find the php.ini file in my system

```
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.2$ cd apache2/
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.2/apache2$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 13  2018 conf.d
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.2/apache2$ cd ..
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.2$ cd 7.1
bash: cd: 7.1: No such file or directory
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.2$ cd ../7.1
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1$ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 18 16:39 cli
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 18 16:39 apache2
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1$ cd apache2/
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 01:32 conf.d
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2$
```

I tried to find using find command

```
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d$ sudo find / -name 'php.ini'
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d$ sudo find / -iname 'php.ini'
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d$ sudo find / -iname 'php.ini'
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
mysystem@mysystem-dev1:/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d$
```

Comment: `locate php.ini`

Comment: @Emmet  please see my updated answer, I have used find command to locate the php.ini file

Comment: Try following solution here, I assume you haven't https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file