# How to can I restart apache server in linux?

Tags: server, apache2, php, laravel

I got error in my laravel project `413 (Payload too large)` on ajax post.

Now I edited the `post_max_size & upload_max_filesize` on `php.ini` file in my 
 *`/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`*.

Now I want to restart `apache server` since I updated the `php.ini` file.

I have done this

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And still got the error.

Is there something missing? Hope anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: I think you need different php.ini file, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the comment, thats true. You have to modify correct ini at correct path.
You have just changed only the cli configuration (PHP called from bash or so (cli)).

So the path should be: /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini.

But it depend on Your distro .. etc

Comment: Working... thank you dude..

Answer (score 1):

You can restart server by following command

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If you use php-fpm you will need to restart this service too. Try

```
systemctl restart php7.<X>-fpm.service
```

where X is the version number of your php

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+Alt+t 
then 
run this command

> sudo service apache2 restart